# What were FN-2187's specific duties in sanitation?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-finn

What is sanitation? What does he do? I'm not look for the why. Does it have something to do with garbage? The garbage compactor?

Comment: There was at least one high profile incident of rebel infiltrators evading capture by escaping through garbage chutes. The First Order wasn't going to make the Empire's mistake of not posting a security guard at the maintenance entrances to the trash compactors. =)

Answer (score 2):

**Sanitation [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=sanitation&oq=sanitation&aqs=chrome..69i57.401j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#safe=active&q=sanitation%20definition):**

> conditions relating to public health, especially the provision of clean drinking water and adequate sewage disposal.

and **Sanitation Worker** [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sanitation-worker):

> a person employed to collect, haul away, and dispose of garbage.

So yes, sanitation has to do with cleanup, including garbage and possibly even sewage. For more on the subject, read about [What does a Sanitation Worker do?](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-does-a-sanitation-worker-do.htm)

The [wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Finn) has the following:

> After crash-landing on the planet, **Finn revealed to Han and Chewie that he used to work on sanitation on Starkiller Base**, much to Solo's annoyance. Finn devised a plan to lower the shield around the planet, which would allow the Resistance pilots to attack the oscillator and destroy the weapon. Chewbacca captured Captain Phasma, and the three forced her to lower the shield. She warned them that her troops would storm in and kill them all, **but Solo asked Finn if there happened to be any convenient trash compactors in the base and they were able to dump her into one via garbage chute.**

Presumably Finn's past in working sanitation was included to 1) be humorous, and 2) allow for a reference to the original *Star Wars* by mentioning trash compactors.

A poster on Quora [says](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Finn-say-he-was-taking-care-of-sanitation-when-he-was-fighting-at-the-beginning-of-the-movie) the following:

> It's pretty clear Finn mentioned his MOS as Sanitation purely as a plot device.
>
> Sanitation is a specialized engineering role responsible for water treatment and plumbing infrastructure.
>
> It's used merely to explain away how Finn is familiar with all parts of the Starkiller Base, and is able to move from one location to another undetected by security.
>
> And a homage to how in the original Luke et al escaped through the garbage disposal system.